# Compile GLFW cannot find -lglfw3

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

I want to learn OpenGL programming with GLFW library. But I have problem when compiling the program. I followed tutorial on http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html and copied the full program. I download the 64-bit version library on http://www.glfw.org/download.html.

I changed the first line from `include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` to `include "GLFW/glfw3.h"`. I've put the GLFW folder inside the folder along with glfw3.dll, glfw3dll, and libglfw3.a

I'm running on Windows 7. This is my gcc version

```
gcc --version
gcc (tdm64-1) 5.1.0
```

I use this command for compiling

```
gcc test.c -Llib-mingw/ -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32
```

But I got this error

```
cannot find -lglfw3
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Is `glfw3.dll` in `./lib-mingw/`?

Comment: There is no `lib-mingw` directory in the 64-bit binary package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having problems with this compilation/linking problem, try set the glfw full lib folder path in gcc or g++ lib path with **-L** parameter, as simplified below. Double quotes and non-relative paths should work.

```
g++ "-L<path_to_glfw>\\glfw\\lib-mingw" -o <executable>.exe <.o files list> -lopengl32 -lglfw3 -lgdi32
```

Two notes:

1. There is no need to pass .a extension. MinGW g++/gcc compiler will automatically understand filename.
2. If you are using the 64-bit version of glfw, switch -L parameter to **\glfw\lib-mingw64** (or respective 64-bit library location folder)